# Oracle SQL: How to get Random Records by each group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 1 million records and 670 groups. I need to pull specific sample size for each group.

Example: If employee1 has performed 200 tasks then I have to pull 132 samples. employee 2 has performed 300 tasks, then I have to pull 169 samples and so on for all 670 employees. The total expected number of samples will be a sum of the total sample tasks derived for each employee.

```
emp total_task sample_task
1   200        132
2   300        169
```

Note: I need the raw data for each group i.e. all 132+169 random samples from 200+300 total records.

Please help.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:sas]?

Comment: Please add more detail, including the things you have tried and how their results aren't what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

So lets first create your sample size table - you need only the sample size, not the total size (this is in your data).

```
create table sample_size as
select 1 emp, 132 sample_size from dual union all
select 2 emp, 169 sample_size from dual;
```

That we simulate some data:

```
create table task as
select 1 emp, rownum task_id from dual connect by level <= 200 union all
select 2 emp, rownum task_id from dual connect by level <= 300 
;
```

You analytic function `ROW_NUMBER` partitioned on your EMPs and ordering in a random order.

Consider as sample only records with a rown mumber less or equal the sample size.

```
with smpl as (
select task.EMP, task.TASK_ID,
case when 
  row_number() over (partition by task.EMP order by dbms_random.value) <= 
  sample_size.sample_size  then 'Y' else 'N' end as is_sample
from task left outer join sample_size on task.emp = sample_size.emp
)
select EMP, TASK_ID 
from smpl 
where is_sample = 'Y';
```

Comment: Awesome. you are the best. This is exactly I was looking for. Thanks a lot.