# Oracle SQL: How to get Random Records by each group with predefined contribution

Tags: sql, oracle

This is with reference to the earlier question described here: [Oracle SQL: How to get Random Records by each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628912/oracle-sql-how-to-get-random-records-by-each-group?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Question:

Is is possible to get the random sample with a ratio of different categories.

Ex: If I have a random record of 132 samples having 3 categories (approved, denied, canceled), how do I get the samples as per below ratio?

```
total sample = 132

category     samples %  sample Size
approved     50%        66
denied       30%        40
canceled     20%        26
```

Note: I need the raw data, not the count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's get some sample data first. I created 132 records with *approved* category to get a 50% sample with 66 rows.

```
create table task as
select 'approved' category, rownum task_id from dual connect by level <= 132 union all
select 'denied' category, rownum task_id from dual connect by level <= 134 union all
select 'canceled' category, rownum task_id from dual connect by level <= 130 
;
```

The key step is to defined the column `RAND_PERC` containg for each category a value between 0 and 1.
If you want a sample of say 50% select all rows in a catagory with a value less or equal .5

The column is caclulated first by assigning the row number in random order (independent for each category) and that divided by the
number of rows in each category.

```
select CATEGORY, TASK_ID, 
 ( row_number() over (partition by task.category order by dbms_random.value)) / 
 ( count(*) over (partition by task.category)) as rand_perc
from task
order by 1,3;

CATEGORY    TASK_ID  RAND_PERC
-------- ---------- ----------
approved         56 ,00757575758 
approved        129 ,0151515152 
approved         61 ,0227272727
```

To draw the sample simple define the WHERE condition as required - see example below.

```
with rnd as (
select CATEGORY, TASK_ID, 
 ( row_number() over (partition by task.category order by dbms_random.value)) / 
 ( count(*) over (partition by task.category)) as rand_perc
from task
)
select CATEGORY, count(*) cnt
from rnd
where 
category = 'approved' and rand_perc <= .5  or /* take 50% from active */
category = 'denied' and rand_perc <= .3  or
category = 'canceled' and rand_perc <= .2
group by CATEGORY
;
```

which gives the sample size as required

```
CATEGORY        CNT
-------- ----------
canceled         26 
denied           40 
approved         66
```

Comment: Awesome. As we both know you are the best @Marmite Bomber. Thanks a lot for the quick response.

Comment: @Badri if it solves the problem you may also accept the answer:)