# Select one random row by group (Oracle 10g)

Tags: sql, oracle, random, group-by, oracle10g

This post is similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842746/oracle-sql-how-to-get-random-records-by-each-group-with-predefined-contribution) in that I have multiple observations per group. However, I want to randomly select only **one** of them. I am also working on Oracle 10g.

There are multiple rows per `person_id` in table `df`. I want to order each group of `person_id`s  by `dbms_random.value()` and select the first observation from each group. To do so, I tried:

```sql
select
    person_id, purchase_date
from
    df
where
    row_number() over (partition by person_id order by dbms_random.value()) = 1
```

The query returns:

> ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here
> 30483. 00000 -  "window  functions are not allowed here"
> *Cause:    Window functions are allowed only in the SELECT list of a query. And, window function cannot be an argument to another window or group function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
select person_id, purchase_date
from (select df.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person_id order by dbms_random.value()) as seqnum
      from df
     ) df
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using `WITH..AS` Clause :

```
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT df.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY dbms_random.value()) AS rn    
   FROM df
)    
SELECT person_id, purchase_date
  FROM t
 WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate queries (using `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions) are much faster than equivalent analytic functions that do the same job. So, if you have a lot of data to process, or if the data is not excessively large but you must run this query often, you may want a more efficient query that uses aggregation instead of analytic functions.

Here is one possible approach:

```
select person_id, 
       max(purchase_date) keep (dense_rank first order by dbms_random.value()) 
           as random_purchase_date
from   df
group  by person_id
;
```